# How to sum all values from list of lists and how to sum every value from every list of lists with each corresponding ones to the other list of lists

Tags: list, python-2.7, for-loop, dynamic, sum

```
a = [[2,8,324,564,35,6],[4,6,23,65,213,5],[432,54,12,65,32,1]]
```

I have the list of lists. How is it possible to sum all values from every list and append them to a second list of lists with for loops because i want it to be dynamic if i use the same code to other list of lists?

I want it to be like:

```
b = [[2+8+324+564+35+6],[4+6+23+65+213+5],[432+54+12+65+32+1]]
```

Next i want to create a third list of lists that will sum all first values, all second values and so on. Also for dynamic purposes.

Like this:

```
c = [[2+4+432],[8+6+54],[324+23+12],[...],[...],[...]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For first one you can use `map()` and `sum()`:

```
>>> a = [[2,8,324,564,35,6],[4,6,23,65,213,5],[432,54,12,65,32,1]]
>>> 
>>> map(sum, a)
[939, 316, 596]
>>>
```

For second one use `map`, `sum` and `zip`:

```
>>> map(sum, zip(*a))
[438, 68, 359, 694, 280, 12]
```

Read more about built-in functions https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html